# how to scrolling image on single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My product image size is height 1600 x  width 600. i can show scrolling image like this website on single product page.

```
  https://envato.com/websites/designs/web-marketing-studio/372e82a3-0b96-4885-b066-88aceb37346d
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... What you want exactly ? The link doesn't describe anything

Comment: please open the link and see product image scrolling feature . https://goo.gl/p8s2Zd .  i can create image like this

Comment: Yes.. It's a simple website with basic layout image text etc.. you give me a screenshot that you want like that

Comment: ok got it.. You meant the monitor has an image with scroll.. ok then I am adding answer here

Comment: i can create image scrolling like this product. this product image scrolling in laptop screen

Comment: hmm then Just set the div product-images a background like that TV. I am editing my answer

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set a height of the containing element that contain the image. And then set that element in css to overflow-y: scroll  in the css. Just basic. Then your image will be shown using scroll..

More specifically for woocommerce .. you can set this css to your style.css

```
.product-images{overflow-y:scroll; background:url(yourimageurl) no-repeat; width:widthof the image height: height of the background image}
```

Comment: just past your css code in style.css file . the product image start  scrolling ?

Comment: i can scrolling image in monitor on single product page.

Comment: Well ........ you are not clear what you need exactly..

Comment: i want similar  products image scrolling function. 
https://goo.gl/p8s2Zd